# Drawing balls from a finite urn (non IID Galton-Watson)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have an urn containing $N$ balls. I begin a process of drawing balls from the urn by taking $1$ ball from the urn (with probability 1). Balls are drawn without replacement.

Each ball that is drawn allows me to select a binomially distributed number of balls that remain in the urn, with constant probability $p$ (I suspect the cases $p<\tfrac{1}{N}$ and $p>\tfrac{1}{N}$ will lead to different behaviour).

Let the process be indexed by $n \in \{1,2,...,N\}$ and the total number of balls drawn at each step be $X_{n}$, and let $S_{n}$ be the accumulated number of balls by then end of step $n$. Then we have:
$$S_{n}=\sum_{i=0}^{n}X_{i},$$ 
and 
$$X_{0}=1,\:\: X_{1}=\sum_{j=1}^{X_{0}} y_{j,0}\:,..., \: X_{k}=\sum_{j=1}^{X_{k-1}} y_{j,k-1}.$$

Further, let the partial sums of $X_{k}$ be given by
$$Y_{t,k-1}=\sum_{j=1}^{t-1}y_{j,k-1},\:\:\: 1\leq t \leq X_{k-1},\:\:\: Y_{1,k-1}=0$$
which represent the accumulation of balls intra-step.

Then, each $y_{j,k-1}$ is binomially distributed $\text{Bin}(N-S_{k-1}-Y_{j,k-1},\:p)$.

I continue this process until I select $0$ total balls in a step, or I exhaust the supply ($N$) of balls (whichever happens first),

$$m^{*}=\min\{m\::\: X_{m}=0 \: \cup \: S_{m}=N\}.$$

This looks like a finite Galton-Watson process with non-IID increments. I am interested in the distribution of total balls drawn, and in the tails in particular:

$$\mathbb{P}(S_{m^{*}} \geq x)\:\:\: \text{for large}\:\: x$$
and $$\text{Var}(S_{m^{*}}).$$

Has this already been solved somewhere, or does anyone have any ideas or references which might be useful to tackle this? I suspect some of my definitions may be non-optimal/deficient (select one) for the problem. My first thought was to consider generating functions, but wondered if this was the best approach.